# Conda hangs in "solving environment" when installing STSci packages

Tags: anaconda, conda, freeze

I run Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a virtual machine on Windows 10. I've installed Anaconda 5.3 without any issues, but when I try to install an STSCI environment with the command line:

```
conda create -n astroconda stsci
```

the terminal gets stuck in "Solving Environment" (I have version 4.5.11 of conda). Yesterday I waited for about 4 hours before giving up. I would like to know if there is a known issue about this problem and if it can be related to the quantity of disk and RAM assigned to the virtual machine.

Comment: My conda is hanging on `Solving environment` when I try to install something from the conda-forge channel. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 12):

I will write a more general solution, to Conda's "Solving Environment" issue, which I had the uttermost pleasure with.

### Short answer of things to try:

- As already mentioned try updating Conda with `conda update conda` or even better, the whole base environment `conda update --all`.
- Specify package and build version using `<package>=<version>=<build>` e.g. `sage=8.3=py27_3`. Search available versions by `conda search <package>`.
- Like for the package, you can also specify python version and ideally some other dependencies. Check dependencies with `conda info <package>`.
- Check current configuration inside the [.condarc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#overview) file or with `conda config --get` and check if you maybe have additional restrictions, as normally you will only find the `channels` defined there.
- When working with additional channels put `conda-forge` or the channel you want to use on top and add `channel_priority: strict`. So your [.condarc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#overview) file would look like this:

```
channel_priority: strict
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

- Contrariwise to the above, remove the first line and try adding `--no-channel-priority` to the command. This one helped me a couple times since updating to Conda 4.6.

### If above does not work:

When conda seem stuck it is possibly having too many options or some conflicts resulting in the SAT solver getting clause counts of multiple millions.

To check if this is the case add `-vv` or `--debug` and you will later see lines like `Invoking SAT with clause count: XXX`. If it stays at one of these lines for long time, then try specifying version for packages as above. If there seem another issue, try the [conda GitHub](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues).

Another useful tip if you are using the `conda-forge` channel, is to go over their [Tips & tricks](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html).

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem on macOS 10.13.6.
The creation of iraf environment

```
conda create -n iraf27 python=2.7 iraf-all pyraf-all stsci
```

works fine instead.

Update: I found out that specifying the python version

```
conda create -n astroconda python=3.6 stsci
```

makes the installer work also with astroconda.

Comment: I, too, had the same problem: conda was hanging for more than 12 hours! Simply specifying a python version got conda past "Solving environment", at last.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but then I updated Conda and it worked...

```
$ conda update conda
```

Comment: this command broke my system and envs when updating to 4.7.7. Think twice before you do it!